# Django OneToOneField - Add to parent or Child?

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-one

What is the proper way to add a OneToOneField in Django? Does it go in the parent class or child class? The official docs don't really explain this. Which way works better with the built-in admin interface? Does it matter? Is there a convention?

What is the "correct" way?

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    portfolio = models.OneToOneField(to="Portfolio", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    ... portfolio fields ...
```

or

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(to="Client", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ... portfolio fields ...
```

I see most examples add it to the child, but it seems adding it to the parent works better with the admin interfaces and makes more sense logically.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to add in child class, but these things are done according to form's presentation, since adding the `portfolio` while adding the client in `Client` model is more logical than adding the `client` in the `Portfolio` model, same goes for ManyToManyField, as documentation says in one of it's example of `Pizza` and `Topping` model, that it's more logical to add how many kinds of toppings in a pizza than adding how many pizzas will be made through particular topping.

So, I'd recommend you to go with first approach.

> Does it matters?

> It's not necessarily matters while querying too, if you query through [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), performance is not affected.